# Is there a way in Sympy to define a constant that works similarly to pi?

Tags: sympy

In Sympy I can use S.Pi in equations that print symbolically but can be evaluated without using sub({pi: 3.1415}):

```
>>> from sympy import pi
>>> from sympy.abc import r
>>> area = pi * r**2; area
πr² 
>>> area.evalf(sub={r: 3.})
￼￼28.274333...
```

I want to do something similar with other constants such as the Stefen-Boltzmann constant, represented by sigma ('σ'). Eg

```
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> sigma, T = symbols('σ T');
>>> radiative_heat = sigma * T**4; radiative_heat
σT⁴
```

Everything is fine up to this point, but I can't assign a permanent value to sigma without changing it to a float, whereas pi already has a value.

```
>>> pi.evalf()
3.14159265...
>>> sigma.evalf()
σ
```

Of course, I can just substitute a value for sigma, but that doesn't read as nicely. I haven't even found where the value for pi is stored in the object.

I've tried using sympy.physics.units, but they don't seem to be implemented that way.

```
>>> import sympy.physics.units as u
>>> sigma = u.stefen
>>> sigma.evalf()
stefan_boltzmann_constant
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The way this sort of thing is handled in cases like `pi` is something like this:

```
class StefanBoltzmann(NumberSymbol):
    def _as_mpf_val(self, prec):
        return Float(5.670374419).evalf(prec)._mpf_

sigma = StefanBoltzmann()

print(sigma.evalf())
```

Obviously the Stefan Boltzmann constant is not really dimensionless so I don't think it would make sense for sympy to implement it like this. There might be a way to convert it to an explicit expression in SI units although I'm not sure how.

Comment: `stefan_boltzmann_constant.convert_to(W/m**2/K**4) -> 1.85294433695108e-10*pi**5*watt/(kelvin**4*meter**2); stefan_boltzmann_constant.scale_factor ->
1.85294433695108e-7*pi**5`

Comment: @oscarbenjamin good point about dimensions. I’m looking to use this with Jupyter for science communications, so I wasn’t as worried about units (I always work in SI). I will look to see if I can do something with @smichr’s comment, though.